# add validation for name was failed

Tags: regex

I use the following regex to validate this need.

1. Should be alpha numeric only
2. Can have hyphen `-` underscore `_` slash `/` and `:`
3. Can have one space at the beginning and at the end ignore spaces

For example..

```
aaa:bbb:ccc
aaa/bbb/ccc
 aa-bb
 dd
```

Currently this validation are not working for ':'
how should I solve it?

```
@"^\s?(?:(?:-?[A-z0-9]+)*|(?:_?[A-z0-9]+)*|(?:\/?[A-z0-9]+/?)*)\s*$"
```

Comment: Allowing spaces at the end or not?

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression.

I'm assuming from your *comment* you want to make sure you have the same delimiter throughout your string.

```
@"^\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:([/:_-])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\1[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)?\s*$"
```

See [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/aK7jC0)

Regular expression:

```
^                 # the beginning of the string
\s?               # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (optional)
[a-zA-Z0-9]+      # any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
(?:               # group, but do not capture (optional)
(                 # group and capture to \1:
 [/:_-]           # any character of: '/', ':', '_', '-'
)                 # end of \1
 [a-zA-Z0-9]+     # any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
 (?:              # group, but do not capture (0 or more times)
  \1              # what was matched by capture \1
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+    # any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
 )*               # end of grouping
)?                # end of grouping
 \s*              # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
$                 # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

You could simplify this a bit.

```
(?i)^\s?[a-z0-9]+(?:([/:_-])[a-z0-9]+(?:\1[a-z0-9]+)*)?\s*$
```

Comment: `a-zA-Z0-9/:_-` can be shortened to `\w/:-`, and this doesn't allow for whitespace at the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you ,there is just two issue with it ,you can add aaa:bbb\cccc which is wrong the sigh should be similiar in the value...second when I add space at the end of the value I got error...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the sign is wrong ? Add this allows space at the end.

Comment: @hwnd: I think he means that when a delimiter is used, it must be the same throughout the entire string (i.e. not `:` somewhere and `/` somewhere else).

Comment: @hwnd-exactly what voithos said :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the regular expression that you're currently using, there's a pattern to the how it's matching the delimiters:

```
//            here                 here                  and here
//            v                    v                     v
@"^\s?(?:  (?:-?[A-z0-9]+)*  |  (?:_?[A-z0-9]+)*  |  (?:\/?[A-z0-9]+/?)*  )\s*$"
```

Notice that it only has `-`, `_`, and `/` - the colon is nowhere to be found. So you *could* just add another section to the expression with the colon...

But don't do that. The regex repeats itself quite a bit, and you can easily make it shorter and more understandable. There are many equally good choices that one can come up with - here's an example, *based on my interpretation that only one delimiter style is allowed, and that the delimiter must not be at the start or end of the string*:

```
^\s?[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:([:\/_-])[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)?\s*$
```

Explanation:

```
^\s?               # start of string, single optional whitespace
[A-Za-z0-9]+       # MUST start with word characters
(?:
  ([:\/_-])        # capture the delimiter
  [A-Za-z0-9]+     # which must be followed by word characters
  (?:
    \1[A-Za-z0-9]+ # repeated strings of the SAME delimiter
  )*               # 0 or more times
)?                 # and, in fact, the entire delimiter section is optional
\s*$               # optional trailing whitespace
```

---

Earlier, I had used the character class `[A-z0-9]`, with the side effect that some extra characters (like `_`) were unintentionally matched. As it turns out, this was due to how character class ranges are defined - [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#PositiveGroup)

> A character range is a contiguous series of characters defined by
>   specifying the first character in the series, a hyphen (-), and then
>   the last character in the series. **Two characters are contiguous if
>   they have adjacent Unicode code points.**

And indeed, the code point of `_` (as well as other characters) is right in between the uppercase and lowercase code points.

The lesson learned: **character ranges are code point ranges, and could include things you wouldn't think they would**.

Comment: I tried your solution and the problem that I can put also aaa_bbb:ccc which is not the same sigh ,any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @JohnJerrby: How funny - turns out the problem was that `[A-z]` (note, uppercase - lowercase) was including non-letter characters (like `_`). Switching to `[A-Za-z]` should fix it (or you can use case-insensitive search `(?i)` like @hwnd showed).